# opencart - mvc - jquery / call function without reload

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

I've been working on a script on opencart that uses jquery $.post .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#contentLeft ul").sortable({
            opacity: 0.6,
            cursor: 'move',
            update: function() {
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings';
                $.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse) {
                    $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
                });
            }
        });
```

In opencart i've created a function in the model that contains what should be in updateDB.php
I was hoping to get this function to be called instead of an external page(updateDB.php)
 and without reloading the current page.

Maybe .post is not the one i should use or is it?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: $.post should be fine. You probably won't be able to access the function directly through the model, but rather create a controller action that calls the model function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying here, but personally I use `$.getJSON` when making requests to opencart.

To use OC's models etc, you will need to create a controller file to access it. For example, if you want to use common/update as your route, you could create the file

> /catalog/controller/common/update.php

Then in there, you would have

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonUpdate extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        //Get "order" parameter
        $order = empty($this->request->get['order']) ? '' : $this->request->get['order'];

        // Load model
        $this->load->model('model/name');

        $result = $this->model_model_name->method($order);

        // Load JSON lib and output content here
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Him trying to do it in the admin part of opencart ... so I guess admin/controller/update ...

Comment: Where exactly does it mention in the admin? Either way, if it was the admin it would be `admin/controller/common/update.php`